# Powershell compare date in .csv

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime, comparison

I have an .xlsx file containing a column 'TransDate' with dates in the format 19/03/2021. I'm using Import-Excel to import the file. I need to **filter out** any rows which have dates **prior** to the last 30 days.
My understanding is that I would need to create a datetime variable for comparison and therefore also convert the dates in the file to datetime in order for the comparison to work?

I have tried the following, however the comparison does not appear to work. If I use -LT I receive ALL lines and if I use -GT I receive zero lines.

Both $PreviousDate and $TransDate return dates in the format '19 March 2021 10:46:47' and are confirmed as a DateTime type.

```
$PreviousDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\INVENTORY\GRN\IMPORT\ -Filter *.xlsx
foreach ($xlsx in $ExcelFiles) {
    $group = Import-Excel $xlsx.FullName -StartRow 1 
    $TransDate = Get-Date ($group[0].'TransDate') 
    $group = $group | Where-Object $PreviousDate -LT $TransDate
}
```

I have since tried this but also have the same result

```
$PreviousDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\INVENTORY\GRN\IMPORT\ -Filter *.xlsx
foreach ($xlsx in $ExcelFiles) {
    $group = Import-Excel $xlsx.FullName -StartRow 1 | Where-Object {
        $_."TransDate" -as [datetime] -gt $PreviousDate
    }
}
```

Comment: As aside, you're missing the opening `{` on `Where-Object`

Comment: You are looping through the items in `group`, but always comparing the same values of `$PreviousDate` and `$TransDate` since these are set outside of the 'loop' of the pipeline and do not change with each iteration.  That is, you are not really filtering the objects in `group`, hence, depending on what these variables are set to before you start, you get all or nothing out.  Typically, you would loop through `group` and compare one or more properties of each object against some predefined value(s) to determine which objects to keep and which to discard.

Comment: Thank You. This does make sense although I'm not sure how to do this within the same pipeline. Could you please make a suggestion?

Comment: The opening `{` after `Where-Object` must be on the same line.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks, it is in my code just had an extra carriage return when posting here. Corrected. But problem still exists

Comment: In your first code you are comparing a **string** to a datetime object.  If `Where-Object { ($_.TransDate -as [datetime]) -gt $PreviousDate}` doesn't work, then try `Where-Object {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.TransDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null) -gt $PreviousDate}`. P.S. I would do `$PreviousDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date` to have that as of midnight.